# Send mail form with AJAX (JavaScript & PHP) doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, ajax

I'm new to Stack Overflow.
I'm trying to have a simple e-mail form on my website, so I've copied one but can't get it to work. The "Send" button just doesn't seem to do anything.
*I am not a programmer and know very little about code*

A friend told me it's as if the PHP isn't recognized.

After following some suggestions I now have the "Send" button working, but I get the "Could not send mail" popup message.

The PHP file gives a "Syntax error, unexpected $EOF" message for line 52 (exit;)
Not sure if this is what's blocking the PHP from running...

HTML code

```
<form id="contact-form" action="" method="POST" class="tm-contact-form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control rounded-0" placeholder="Full Name" required />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control rounded-0" placeholder="Email" required />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" id="contact-select" name="inquiry">
            <option value="-">Subject</option>
            <option value="3DPrints">3D Prints</option>
            <option value="AmpsEffects">Amps &amp; Effect Pedals</option>
            <option value="Other">Other</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea rows="8" style="resize: none;" name="message" class="form-control rounded-0" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mb-4">
        <div id="result-message" class="alert alert-success d-none">Send result message will display here</div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group tm-text-right">
        <button type="submit" class="tm-btn tm-btn-primary">Send</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

JS file

```
jQuery(function ($) { // DOM ready and $ alias in scope

    const $message = $("#result-message");

    $("#contact-form").on("submit", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const FD = new FormData(this);

        $message.text("Sending email...").removeClass("d-none");

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "js/call-form.php",
            dataType: "json", // Expected response format
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            data: FD,
        })
            .always(function (data) {
                $message.text(data.message).addClass(data.status === "error" ? "alert-danger" : "alert-success");
            })
            .fail(function (err) {
                $message.text("!!! Could not send email").addClass("alert-danger");
            });
    });

});
```

PHP file

```
<?php

if (
    isset($_POST['name']) &&
    isset($_POST['email']) &&
    isset($_POST['inquiry']) &&
    isset($_POST['message'])
) {

    $to = "info@hemmelaudio.com";
    $subject = $_POST['inquiry'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $html = <<<EX
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-GB">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>$subject</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
            <tbody>
                <tr><th>From:</th><td>$name</td></tr>
                <tr><th>Email:</th><td>$email</td></tr>
                <tr><th>message:</th><td>$message</td></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
    </html>
EX; // !! Don't indent this line !!

    $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: Hemmelaudio.com\r\n";

    $isSent = mail($to, $subject, $html, $headers);
    echo json_encode([
        "status" => ($isSent ? "success" : "error"),
        "message" => ($isSent ? "Email is sent" : "Email is not sent"),
    ]);
} else {
    echo json_encode([
        "status" => "error",
        "message" => "Missing fields"
    ]);
}

exit;
```

I have put the PHP file with 755 permissions.

Please help!
Thanks

Comment: Your form tag doesn't have anything in the action attribute. It should have the path tp the PHP file. Otherwise, the form doesn't know where to send the data.

Comment: @SloanThrasher you're forgetting that he does not need necessarily one since he uses the $.ajax's `url:`

Comment: where are you hosting your site?

Comment: What is the folder structure? Maybe the url inside the ajax call is wrong.

Comment: Hosting site on WHC.ca

Comment: `js/call-form.php` ... why inside a js/ folder? I would never expect to find .php files  inside a js/ folder :)

Comment: @tdesero The URL in the JS file has been tried as "js/call-form.php", "./call-form.php" and "call-form.php". All three fail. The PHP is in the JS folder.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Well I didn't really know where to put the PHP file. Should I put it somewhere else? Does it really matter?

Comment: If the file is located at yourdomain.com/js/call-form.php probably „/js/call-form.php“ could work.

Comment: @tdesero Just tried putting "/js/call-form.php", still doesn't work.

Comment: By the way, my HTML file has the line <script src="js/send-email-ajax.js"></script> in it

Comment: @Hemmel thanks for the info - I'll try to replicate on my localhost and BRB to you soon

Comment: I don't know what happened to one of the answers but it disappeared. I tried what was suggested and got to a point where now I get a popup message saying "It's not OK!". So I guess the JS runs now but the PHP doesn't.

Comment: I'm sad to see that this question was closed. We were on the verge of getting answers.

Comment: Question answered. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use FormData API with $.ajax's `processData: false,` and `contentType: false,`
- Use `dataType: "json",` not <s>`dataType: "test/json",`</s>
- Use `$.ajax`'s `.always()` if you're gong to define the response *status*
- Learn about the benefits of [Heredoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)
- Use a proper HTML-email Doctype
- Use `<label>` as wrapper.
- `'.$_POST['inquiry'].'` ?! Please use a better code editor. It will highlight the errors for you.

index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>MY PAGE</title>
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <style>
            label.form-group {
                display: block;
                max-width: none;
            }
            textarea {
                resize: vertical;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form id="contact-form" action="" method="POST" class="tm-contact-form">
            <label class="form-group">
                <span class="control-label col-lg-3">Full name:</span>
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Full Name" required value="Lorem Ipsum" />
            </label>

            <label class="form-group">
                <span class="control-label col-lg-3">Email:</span>
                <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Full Name" required value="text@example.com" />
            </label>

            <label class="form-group">
                <span class="control-label col-lg-3">Subject:</span>
                <select class="form-control" name="inquiry" required>
                    <option value="3DPrints">3D Prints</option>
                    <option value="AmpsEffects">Amps &amp; Effect Pedals</option>
                    <option value="Other">Other</option>
                </select>
            </label>

            <label class="form-group">
                <span class="control-label col-lg-3">Message:</span>
                <textarea name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Message" required>Test message</textarea>
            </label>

            <div id="result-message" class="d-none form-group mb-4 alert alert-primary"></div>

            <div class="form-group tm-text-right">
                <button type="submit" class="tm-btn tm-btn-primary">Send</button>
            </div>
        </form>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script
            src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
        ></script>
        <script
            src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
        ></script>
        <script src="js/send-email-ajax.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

js/send-email-ajax.js

```js
jQuery(function ($) { // DOM ready and $ alias in scope

    const $message = $("#result-message");

    $("#contact-form").on("submit", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const FD = new FormData(this);

        $message.text("Sending email...").removeClass("d-none");

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "js/call-form.php",
            dataType: "json", // Expected response format
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            data: FD,
        })
            .always(function (data) {
                $message.text(data.message).addClass(data.status === "error" ? "alert-danger" : "alert-success");
            })
            .fail(function (err) {
                $message.text("!!! Could not send email").addClass("alert-danger");
            });
    });

});
```

js/call-form.php:

```php
<?php

if (
    isset($_POST['name']) &&
    isset($_POST['email']) &&
    isset($_POST['inquiry']) &&
    isset($_POST['message'])
) {

    $to = "info@hemmelaudio.com";
    $subject = $_POST['inquiry']; // '.$_POST['inquiry'].'; ?! please, use a better code editor
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $html = <<<EX
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-GB">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>$subject</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
            <tbody>
                <tr><th>From:</th><td>$name</td></tr>
                <tr><th>Email:</th><td>$email</td></tr>
                <tr><th>message:</th><td>$message</td></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
    </html>
EX; // !! Don't indent this line !!

    $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: Hemmelaudio.com\r\n";

    $isSent = mail($to, $subject, $html, $headers);
    echo json_encode([
        "status" => ($isSent ? "success" : "error"),
        "message" => ($isSent ? "Email is sent" : "Email is not sent"),
    ]);
} else {
    echo json_encode([
        "status" => "error",
        "message" => "Missing fields"
    ]);
}

exit;
```

Comment: I tried changing the js and PHP to what you put, but there's a "unexpected EOF" on the PHP. I'm trying to figure out how to correct this.

Comment: Ok for a weird reason the "// !! Don't indent this line !!" was interfering with the parsing. After removing it, the PHP code works.